# jquery / json output data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

im having some problems outting my returned array - on console log it shows

```
    {
   "text":"{\"error\":false,\"msg\":\"found in search\"}",
   "data":{
      "notifications":[

      ]
   }
}
```

im using

```
success : function(data){               
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success').text(data.msg).show(500);
            if (data.error === true)
                $('#restricted_locator').show(500);
        },
```

however data.msg returns undefined, but now looking at the array its got nothing to fetch but how can i change to get the data from text?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if it shows this log output when you log data, then just try data.text

Comment: data.text shows the array of data but i need to get the data within the array - the output when i use that is what i placed above

Comment: sorry when i console data i get that above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you have to parse "data" to JSON using `jQuery.parseJSON(data)` or `$.parseJSON(data)` so your code should be:

```
function(data) {               
    var data_obj = $.parseJSON( data.text );

    $('#waiting').hide(500);
    $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data_obj.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success').text(data_obj.msg).show(500);

    if (data_obj.error === true)
        $('#restricted_locator').show(500);
    },
```

Comment: well, there you have it, "data" is empty, I would suggest making the request in Chrome and look in the console at the XHR request, right-click -> open in new tab, see if you actually get the string that needs to be converted into JSON.

Comment: i used parseJSON(data.text) instead and worked perfect! thanks for right direction

Comment: awesome, I'm glad you've figured it out! (:

Answer (score 0):

I assume the console output which have in the question is the data object. And as per that you should use `data.text.msg` for setting the text and `data.text.error` for checking error.

Try this.

```
$('#message')
.removeClass()
.addClass((data.text.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
.show(500)//I am deliberately calling show first because you will see the element atelast
.text(data.text.msg || "no message");//If there is no msg you will at least see "no message" just to confirm you that msg is undefined or null
```

Comment: the data object from above is when i console.log(data.text)

Comment: sorry my mistake, when i console log data i get that above result returned but i tried as you suggested before and returned undefined

Comment: Can check console.log(data.text)?

Comment: sorry, i used that and got no message back on the page!

Comment: console.log(data.text) returns {"error":false,"msg":"found in search"}

Comment: Then the above code should work perfectly fine. What do you see in the `#message`?

Comment: i got it working using var data_obj = $.parseJSON(data.text); then using data_obj.msg and worked a treat!